# Kafka Event received 10 times when exceptions occur

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Our application use Spring Kafka and I have a problem with the consumer.

Backend "Producer"

```
public void sendEvent(final DomainObject obj) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send("topicA", obj);
}
```

Backend "Consumer"

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = {"topicA"}
)
public void onSendEvent(final DomainObject obj) {
  this.customService.doSomething(obj)
}
```

If not exception is throwed, the consumer receive the event 1 time but when an exception is throwed from "doSomething" method (RuntimeException), my consumer receive the event 10 times and I don't understand why.

I tried to set a retry template with a retryPolicy in my consumer but nothing change:

```
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(getSimpleRetryPolicy());
    return retryTemplate;
}

private SimpleRetryPolicy getSimpleRetryPolicy() {
    return new SimpleRetryPolicy(1);
}
```

Here is my consumer config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, DomainEvent> consumerFactory(@Autowired KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                                            @Autowired KafkaConsumerCustomization consumerCustomization) {
    final JsonDeserializer<DomainEvent> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    jsonDeserializer.getTypeMapper().setTypePrecedence(Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID);
    jsonDeserializer.configure(Map.of(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, consumerCustomization.getFlatIdClassMapping()), false);
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages(consumerCustomization.getTrustedPackages());
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerCustomization.getConsumerId());
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, DomainEvent> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        @Autowired ConsumerFactory<String, DomainEvent> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, DomainEvent> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}

private RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(getSimpleRetryPolicy());
    return retryTemplate;
}

private SimpleRetryPolicy getSimpleRetryPolicy() {
    return new SimpleRetryPolicy(1);
}

public static class KafkaConsumerCustomization {

    private final String[] trustedPackages;
    private final Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping;
    private final String consumerId;

    public KafkaConsumerCustomization(String[] trustedPackages, final Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping, String consumerId) {
        this.trustedPackages = trustedPackages;
        this.idClassMapping = idClassMapping;
        this.consumerId = consumerId;
    }

    public String[] getTrustedPackages() {
        return trustedPackages;
    }

    public String getFlatIdClassMapping() {
        return idClassMapping.entrySet().stream()
                             .map(stringClassEntry -> stringClassEntry.getKey() + ":" + stringClassEntry.getValue().getCanonicalName())
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

    public Map<String, Class<?>> getIdClassMapping() {
        return idClassMapping;
    }

    public String getConsumerId() {
        return consumerId;
    }
}
```

}

and my producer config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, DomainEvent> kafkaTemplate(@Autowired final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(this.producerFactory((kafkaProperties)));
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, DomainEvent> producerFactory(final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(), new StringSerializer(), new JsonSerializer<>());
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs i would recommend using [SeekToCurrentErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/_reference.html#seek-to-current) to retry or skip the failed records

> Starting with version 2.2, the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler can now recover (skip) a record that keeps failing. By default, after 10 failures, the failed record will be logged (ERROR). You can configure the handler with a custom recoverer (BiConsumer) and/or max failures.

```
SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler =
new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
    // recover after 3 failures - e.g. send to a dead-letter topic
}, 3);
```

And for batch listerner

> The SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler seeks each partition to the first record in each partition in the batch so the whole batch is replayed. This error handler does not support recovery because the framework cannot know which message in the batch is failing.

Comment: That is correct. Starting with version 2.5, the default error handler is the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`  with it's defaults (10 delivery attempts with no back-off). https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#x25-container

Comment: Yeah it works ! Thank you for your help ! Now the event pass how many times I want. Now I have another problem yet : the event is sent again if i restart my backend consumer. Do you know why ?

Comment: That should be another question, but i believe it is an offset commit issue, make sure your consumer is commit offset before your application terminates @CédricB

Comment: Indeed, the following code resovle my problem: 
_errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);_ Thank you !